# How to make a stacked bar chart where the total measure is always fixed at 100%?

Tags: tableau-api

I am attempting to create a 100% stacked bar chart in Tableau where the total stacked measure is always equal to 100% on the axis in order to make a productivity dashboard. I want all filter options to look like the first picture attached below where the total stretches and stops at 100%. However, some cases break this rule, such as going over 100% or when the "All" option is selected and stretches it 700%.

I tried fixing the axis max at 100% and it works perfectly for all the individual employees but since the "All" selection goes up to 700%, it just shows it all the way full at 100%. Is there anyway to make my total measure, in this case "Goal", always set to 100% no matter what the number is? This is my current formula for my total measure of "Goal" `{Fixed [Contractor], Date: SUM([Goal])} / {Fixed [Contractor], [Date]: SUM([Goal])}`

Thank you for any help!

Employee 1 with normal productivity where the axis is staying at 100%.
[image: Employee 1 with normal productivity.]

Employee 2 going over 100% where the axis then stretches past 100%.
[image: Employee 2 going over 100% as seen by axis.]

All employees added up where it stretches the axis to over 700%.
[image: All employees added up where it stretches the axis to over 700%.]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with the "Compute Using" attributes for the table calculation.  Since table calculations are secondary calculations on top of your existing measures you have the flexibility for how they are calculated.

Here is how to adjust this.  Click on your measure and select "Edit Table Calculation..."

[image: Table calcs]

To get the same result as you I will want the table calculation to calculate on "Table (across)" which will look at the dimension (in my picture, Category) instead of by Category AND Month.  The little numbers in brackets and the yellow highlights are especially helpful in showing you how the calculations are being interpreted.

See the default "Table (down)" and the desired "Table (across)" calculations in the screenshot below.  You will likely want the same but it might depend on your exact Viz setup.

[image: Table (down)]

[image: Table (across)]